# Several sourceConfig for one section

Tags: c#, app-config

Example:
I have App.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <example configSource="example.config" />
</configuration>
```

I would like to assign several sources for an example section. Is this possible?

Comment: Why you have multiple same config sections? Can you explain the actual use case? You can not have same config section declared more than once in app.config .

Comment: I have one default section declaration and other custom declarations that cannot work together. The one that is included depends on build settings. So I have one default and one custom file. I would like to achieve a state in which these two files were "merged". Is it even possible?